# how to ignore core locator for one element

Tags: jdi, jdiframework

[locators tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxAqz.png)

In my case i have a selector list not in a core window. For window used locator ".uni-DialogBox" but listLocator(.gwt-Label.selectbox-item__label) not in this dom [ERROR 54:49.549] : >>> NewOrderWindow.orderType (>css='.uni-DialogBox'>css='.gwt-Label.selectbox-item__label')
, see screen. How ignore parent locator only for one locator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Root annotation for an element in order to use only its locator like

```
@Root @UI("'.gwt-Label.selectbox-item__label") 
UIElement enter;
```

Or switch off inherited locators for the whole project in test.properties 
smart.search=off
or 
smart.search=false